# How prove $\sum_{i=2}^na_i^{1-\frac{1}{i}} < S+2\sqrt{S}$ for $S=a_2+\dots +a_n.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_2,\dots,a_n>0$ and $S=a_2+\dots +a_n.$ How prove $\sum_{i=2}^na_i^{1-\frac{1}{i}} < S+2\sqrt{S}.$

Comment: what have you try it?

Comment: for n=2, $\sqrt{a_{2} } < a_{2}+ 2\sqrt{a_{2} } =S_{2}+2\sqrt{S_{2}}$, for n+1  $\sum_{i=2}^{n+1} a_i^{1-\frac{1}{i}} =\sum_{i=2}^{n}a_i^{1-\frac{1}{i}} +a_{n+1}^{1-\frac{1}{n+1}} < S_{n}+2\sqrt{S_{n}} + a_{n+1}^{1-\frac{1}{n+1}} <....(what?)$

Answer (score -1):

Because $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^{1-\frac{1}{i}}=\sum_{i=2}^na_i^{1-\frac{1}{i}}+1 < S+2\sqrt{S}+1=(\sqrt S +1)^2 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=2}^na_i^{1-\frac{1}{i}} < S+2\sqrt{S}.$

$ \ $

It's sufficient to show $(\sqrt S +1)^2 >  {\sum_{i=1}^na_i^{1-\frac{1}{i}}}\tag 1 $

Suppose $S_n=a_2+\dots +a_n.$

**Prove by induction:**

**When $n=1,2$ (1) holds obviously.**

**If $m=n-1\ge 2$ holds,then for $m=n$:**

$(\sqrt S_{n-1} + 1)^2 +a_n^{1-\frac 1n}=S_{n-1}+1+2\sqrt S_{n-1}+a_n^{1-\frac 1n} 
\\ =S_n+1+2\sqrt S_{n-1}<S_n+1+2\sqrt S_{n}=(\sqrt S_n +1)^2$

**Hence $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{1-\frac{1}{i}} < (\sqrt S_{n-1} + 1)^2+a_n^{1-\frac 1n} < (\sqrt S_n +1)^2$**

Comment: @math110 Why? Could you point it out?